# What is the "predictions for different feature values" curve in a catboost feature plot?

Tags: catboost

The plot I am referring to can be found [here](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostregressor_calc_feature_statistics.html). It is reproduced by calling the calc_feature_statistics function.

It is clear to me what the blue and orange curve (mean target and mean prediction) represent. 
What is the red line(predictions for different feature values) ?

Answer (score 2):

from the link:

> To calculate it, the value of the feature is successively changed to fall into every bucket for every input object. The value for a bucket on the graph is calculated as the average for all objects when their feature values are changed to fall into this bucket.

As far as I understand these words the explanation is as next:

for example you've got categorical feature with three possible values: 'Moscow', 'London', 'New York'. Then:

1. Let's set all values of this feature in train data as 'Moscow' and
   calculate average prediction among all of the data with the model we
   trained earlier. This will be the dot of red line for bucket
   'Moscow'
2. Repeat previous step with value 'London' --> this will be dot of red line for bucket 'London'
3. Same for New York.